# XPath for attribute in parent not containing a specific character?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

What would be the XPath expression to determine if the parent node does not contain a specific character?

Given the following XML:

```xml
<root>
  <parent id="parent_1" attr="ABC">
    <child id="child_11"/>
    <child id="child_12"/>
  </parent>
  <parent id="parent_2" attr="XYZ">
    <child id="child_21"/>
    <child id="child_22"/>
  </parent>
</root>
```

What would the XPath expression to test which children have the parent that does not contain the character **Y** in its attribute **`attr`**?

Being the answer children with id: **`child_11`** and **`child_12`**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//child[not(contains(../@attr, "Y"))]
```

will select all `child` elements that do not have a parent with an `attr` attribute value that contains a `"Y"`,

```
<child id="child_11"/>
<child id="child_12"/>
```

as requested.